# How to get values from another menu without refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

I present a popup menu when radio buttons on a form are clicked. I used bootstrap module to popup the new menu.

When I select the option from the popup menu the the form is reset. The previously entered form values are lost.

Here is the code for my menu and module.
Hosted link is also available here: www.dbghale.ml

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Booking Hotel</title>
  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">


  <!-- for the editing javascript -->
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  <!-- for the datepicker function -->
  <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
  <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>

<body>
  <div class="col-md-12 gap2"></div>
  <div class="booking">
    <div class="container">

      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-10 bookingpart">

        <center>
          <h3>Hotel Booking</h3>
        </center>

        <form method="POST" action="index.php">

          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <label>Checkin Date</label>
            <div class="controls input-append date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy"
              data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
              <input type="text" name="checkinn" value="" readonly placeholder="Checkin Date" class="form-control required glyphicon glyphicon-calendar ">
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <label>Checkout Date</label>
            <div type="text" class="controls input-append date form_date" data-date="" data-date-format="dd MM yyyy"
              data-link-field="dtp_input2" data-link-format="yyyy-mm-dd">
              <input type="text" name="checkoutt" value="" readonly placeholder="Checkout Date"
                class="form-control required">
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-remove"></i></span>
              <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
            </div>

          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <label><br>Location</label>
            <select name="hotel_location" id="hotel_location" class="form-control">
                                <option>Select One</option>
                                <option value="KATHMANDU">KATHMANDU</option>


                      </select>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><br>Category</label>


              <br>
              <input type="radio" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1">
              <span
                class="mytext" name="hotel_category" value="3"> 3 star</span>

                <input type="radio" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">
                <span
                  class="mytext" name="hotel_category" value="3"> 4 star</span>
                  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
                  <input type="radio" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3">
                  <span
                    class="mytext" name="hotel_category" value="3"> 5 star</span>


                    <div class=" text-right">

                      <!-- tested for without submitting form -->
                      <!-- <?php
                                 if(isset($_GET['age']))
                                 {

                                  $value=$_GET['value'];

                                  if($value==1){$hotel="Hotel Himalaya"; $type="Double Deluxe room"; $price="US$ 126.00";}
                                      if($value==2){$hotel="Hotel Himalaya"; $type="Exclusive room"; $price="US$ 159.00";}

                                    echo $hotel,"<br>" .$type, "<br>" .$price; 
                                  }    
                                  ?> -->

                      <?php
                                     if(isset($_POST['submitfs']))
                                     {
                                      global $hotel, $type, $price;
                                      $value=$_POST['selected'];

                                      if($value==1){$hotel="Hotel Himalaya"; $type="Double Deluxe room"; $price="US$ 126.00";}
                                      if($value==2){$hotel="Hotel Himalaya"; $type="Exclusive room"; $price="US$ 159.00";}
                                      if($value==3){$hotel="Hotel Himalaya"; $type="Junior Suit"; $price="US$ 199.00";}

                                      if($value==4){$hotel="Dwarika’s Hotel"; $type="Heritage Deluxe Double room "; $price="US$ 303.00";}
                                      if($value==5){$hotel="Dwarika’s Hotel"; $type="Junior Suit"; $price="US$ 399.00";}
                                      if($value==6){$hotel="Dwarika’s Hotel"; $type="Executive Suite"; $price="US$ 542.00";}
                                      if($value==7){$hotel="Dwarika’s Hotel"; $type="Royal Suite"; $price="US$ 2021.00";}

                                      if($value==8){$hotel="Hyatt Regency"; $type="Double Guest Room"; $price="US$ 159.00";}
                                      if($value==9){$hotel="Hyatt Regency"; $type="Stupa View Room"; $price="US$ 185.00";








                                          echo $hotel,"<br>" .$type, "<br>" .$price; 

                                          $_SESSION['hotell']=$hotel;
                                          $_SESSION['typee']=$type;
                                          $_SESSION['pricee']=$price;

                                     } 
                                  ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><br>Firstname</label>
              <input name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" class="form-control required"
                type="text">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label><br>Lastname</label>
              <input name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" class="form-control  required"
                type="text">
            </div>
          </div>


          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Email</label>
              <input name="email_address" id="email_address" placeholder="Email Address" class="form-control email required"
                type="text">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Contact No</label>
              <input name="contact_no" id="contact_no" placeholder="Contact No" class="form-control required"
                type="text">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12 ">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label>Message</label>
              <textarea name="message" id="contact_no" placeholder="Contact No" class="form-control required"></textarea>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-6">
            <div class="form-group">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary custom_btn" name="submit_btn" id="hotel_submit_btn">SUBMIT</button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>


        <!-- working for the mail function -->
        <?php 
                 if(isset($_POST['submit_btn']))
                 {
                    $hotell=$_SESSION['hotell'];
                    $typee=$_SESSION['typee'];
                    $pricee=$_SESSION['price'];

                    $fname=$_POST['firstname'];
                    $lname=$_POST['laststname'];

                    $location=$_POST['hotel_location'];
                    $checkindate=$_POST['checkinn'];
                    $checkoutdate=$_POST['checkoutt'];

                    $email=$_POST['email_address'];
                    $contact=$_POST['contact_no'];
                    $message=$_POST['message'];

                    $to='db.ghale65@gmail.com';
                    $subject='Hotel Booking';

                    $body = " \n
                        Booking Info \n
                             Category : $hotell
                             Room : $typee 
                             Price : $pricee
                             CheckIn Date : $checkindate 
                             Checkout Date : $checkoutdate 

                        Booked By \n
                             Name : $fname,  $name 
                             Email: $email
                             Contact: $contact 

                             Message : $message 
                             ";


                          if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) 
                          { 
                            echo '<script> alert("Booking is sucess !!!")</script>';
                          } 
                          else { 
                          echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
                          }  


                 } 
                 ?>


      </div>
      <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-12">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <!-- bootstrap js including -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


  <!-- jquery cdn -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- from the date picker -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/locales/bootstrap-datetimepicker.fr.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.form_datetime').datetimepicker({
      //language:  'fr',
      weekStart: 1,
      todayBtn: 1,
      autoclose: 1,
      todayHighlight: 1,
      startView: 2,
      forceParse: 0,
      showMeridian: 1
    });
    $('.form_date').datetimepicker({
      language: 'en',
      weekStart: 1,
      todayBtn: 1,
      autoclose: 1,
      todayHighlight: 1,
      startView: 2,
      minView: 2,
      forceParse: 0
    });
    $('.form_time').datetimepicker({
      language: 'fr',
      weekStart: 1,
      todayBtn: 1,
      autoclose: 1,
      todayHighlight: 1,
      startView: 1,
      minView: 0,
      maxView: 1,
      forceParse: 0
    });

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I want the values of not to reset when I select options from the popup menu.

[image: screen shot of the page is here.]

Comment: Hi, there's no need to copy and paste _all_ your code here. The question would be a lot easier to read if you just post the bits that are important to your question.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get better answers, please read how to create a [mcve]. If your question is only about JS - don't include the php tag and remove any unrelated php code.

Comment: #Mig82 please look on link www.dbghale.ml and fill the form then you will see problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ajax from jquery. you can call file some value of html tags from other file php.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url:'ekstrnal_file.php',
            success:function(e){
            $("select").html(e);
            }
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are sending the whole page back from a POST or a Get, hence starting the page from scratch again.

In the PHP, test if you are requesting or setting values only. You don't need to send back the html page, it is all ready in the browser.
If you are requesting data from the PHP in the page, test that at the top of the code, and just return with out refreshing the page.

```html
  <?php
    if(isset($_POST[''submit_btn''))
    {
        echo CallSomeFunctionWithThePostRequest($_POST['submit_btn']);
         return; // don't continuing loading the default page.
    }
    ?>
    < !DOCTYPE html>
    < html lang="en">
    < head>
      ... rest of the page. ....
    < input id="aFormInput" onclick="jsMakeAjaxCallToPage(SomeRequstData);" .  >
    <div id="putResponceHere" ></div>
    < script>
     function jsMakeAjaxCallToPage(SomeRequstData)
      {
     // use an async call to get/set the data.   
     xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
     if( xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status ==200)
     {
       // Your php response is in xhttp.responseText;      
        document.getElementById("putResponceHere").innerHTML= http.responseText;
     } };
     xhttp.open("POST", "",true); //PORT request to the same url as the page.
     xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
     xhttp.send("?request="+SomeRequestData);
     return(false); // don't do the default button action.
    }
    </script>
```

This is quick rough out to give you the idea.

Comment: Thank you for writing this codes for me ! @BitSmith